# Automate non-rooted android smartphone

Tags: python, bash, shell, automation

Can we automate non-rooted android smartphone remotely using any script?

In Windows/Linux/Mac we can write commands and we can send it to anyone via link, and that commands will be executed automatically.

Can we do same in android too??

Assume the android is not rooted, no physical access, no ADB .

Comment: "no physical access"? Are you trying to hack the smartphone, then?

Comment: Yes I am a penetration testing student. I am trying to exploit my own android.